# Methods to find out how categorical choices contribute to an optimal value

Tags: regression, machine-learning, optimization

Say I need to create $200$ objects. I need to use $3$ processes to build a single object, let's call these processes $A,B,C$. Each of these processes can be executed in two ways. So process $A$ can be executed either by using method $a_1$ or $a_2$. Process $B$ can be executed using either method $b_1$ or $b_2$. And process $C$ can be executed using either method $c_1$ or $c_2$.

Once an object is created, it is evaluated and given a value $v$.

As there are 2 ways of executing each process, and there are 3 processes, that means there are 8 different combinations possible to create an object.

Say I created 200 objects with each of these 8 combinations of methods. I then have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Attempt      A    B    C    v
1            a1   b1   c1   1.9
1            a1   b1   c2   4.0
1            a1   b2   c1   1.8
1            a1   b2   c2   2.5
1            a2   b1   c1   1.8
1            a2   b1   c2   4.2
1            a2   b2   c1   1.7
1            a2   b2   c2   2.0
2            a1   b1   c1   1.7
2            a1   b1   c2   4.5
.            .    .    .    .
.            .    .    .    .
200          a2   b2   c2   3
```

So for a given combination of methods, say $(a_1,b_1,c_1)$, I have created 200 objects, and have a distribution of values for those 200 objects. I have such a distribution for each of the 8 possible combinations of methods.

I want to know what the combination of methods is that led to the largest average value. This is of course easy to do, as I can just average over the 200 values for each method combination and pick the largest one.

**My question is this**. I would like to gain some insight into the relationship between the choice of methods for $A,B,C$. Specifically:

1. How important are each of the choices? Perhaps the choice of method for executing process $B$ and $C$ have no impact on the value of the produced object, and it's all down to the choice between $a_1$ and $a_2$ for $A$?
2. The relationships between choices. Perhaps $a_1$ is better when combined with $b_2$, but $a_2$ is better when combined with $b_1$.

What methods are available for me to gain such insight? I was considering using a regression model on the categorical variables in order to answer point (1).

In addition to a solution, some insight into available options would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Is there any uncertainty here? If the value is fixed for any combination, then you can just list your options and compare them.

Comment: This question contains some confusing elements. Evidently "Object ID" is not an identifier, because it repeats across rows.  What is it intended to represent, then?  Given there are only six possible combinations of processes and performance methods, either (a) the value depends only on process and performance method and you can just create six objects and choose the combination with the largest value or (b) the value is a random variable.  In that case, it has no definite maximum, so what exactly are you trying to maximize?  Expectation? Chance of exceeding some threshold?  Something else?

Comment: Have edited the question. Hopefully it's clearer now?